# Biblatex entry type @online: endash in field year

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I want to add an endash to the year field of an online resource

```
@Online{Galebach:2002,
  author        = {Brian Galebach},
  title         = {Collection of n-uniform tilings},
  year          = {2002--2018},
  url           = {http://probabilitysports.com/tilings.html},
  urldate       = {2018-05-06},
}
```

However, `--` is not typeset as an endash but just two regular hyphens:
[image]

Also the command `\endash` does not work.

I use biblatex with biber.

Comment: This might depend on your font set-up. Can you please provide a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). A `--` in the `year` field does work for me, even though I'm tempted to say it is wrong and would urge you to use the ISO format `date = {2002/2018}`.

Comment: Just for the record: the endash for page ranges is shown correctly. Therefore I was assuming it was not an issue with my font set-up. I now use the ISO format date and an endash indicating the range is displayed.

Comment: If you use an up-to-date version of `biblatex` the en-dash between page ranges is produced automatically even if you manually input `5--6` what `biblatex` will print is `5\bibrangedash 6`. So the real question is whether or not a bare `--` in your document body produces an en-dash as desired.

Comment: Your comments are really helpful: I didn't know that biblatex converts the page range `--` to `\bibrangedash`. And as you probably expected a bare `--` does not produce an en-dash in my document. I suspect there is already a question out there which adresses this. Thanks for clarifying this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is `\textendash`, or you directly enter  `–` on the keyboard. This being said, the recommended syntax to enter a range of years , as documented in §2.3.8, *Date and Time Specifications*, is

```
date={2002/2018}
```

Comment: I switched to the field `date` with the recommended syntax for a range `date={2002/2018}` and it works as wished. Also thanks for mentioning the relevant section in the documentation of biblatex!